# Two tables next to each other

Tags: tables, booktabs

How can I get two tables next to each other?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \small
    \begin{spacing}{0.6}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}

            \toprule
            \textbf{Modelo} & \textbf{RMSE}\\ \midrule
            A & $0.9399$ \\ 
            B  & $0.9381$ \\
            C & $0.9333$ \\
            D \\ 
            E & $0.9083$ \\

            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{spacing}

\end{table}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \small
    \begin{spacing}{0.6}
        \begin{tabular}{@{}lr@{}}

            \toprule
            \textbf{Modelo} & \textbf{RMSE}\\ \midrule
            A & $0.9399$ \\ 
            B  & $0.9381$ \\
            C & $0.9333$ \\
            D \\ 
            E & $0.9083$ \\

            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{spacing}

\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the answer is accepted please tick the checkmark on the left side of the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what is required?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}        
\begin{document}   
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\quad}c@{\quad}c}
    $R_1$   &   $R_2$   &   $R_3$   \\
\begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
    \hline
\textbf{course}     & \textbf{type} \\  \hline
               A & $0.9399$ \\ 
            B  & $0.9381$ \\
            C & $0.9333$ \\
            D &\\ 
            E & $0.9083$            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
    &   \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
        \hline
    \textbf{course} & \textbf{deg}  \\  \hline
        A & $0.9399$ \\ 
            B  & $0.9381$ \\
            C & $0.9333$ \\
            D &\\ 
            E & $0.9083$            \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
        &   \begin{tabular}[t]{|c|c|}
            \hline
        \textbf{course} & \textbf{course\_num}  \\  \hline
        Databases       & 55281                 \\  \hline
        Math            & 55570                 \\  \hline
            \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```